# Problem with "Get Lowest Value" Method in 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with this one program I'm writing.  I have to do a getTotal, Average, highest and lowest.  The thing is, everything is working except the last method, getLowest, which gives me the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
at TwoDim.getLowest(TwoDim.java:66)
at TwoDim.main(TwoDim.java:15)
"
Additionally it says "unreachable code" in Eclipse and tells me to get rid of the "return low;" line at the end.  I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here, it should work totally fine but it isn't.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;

class TwoDim
{
    //main function
    public static void main (String []arg)
    {
        int [][]list= {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
        //Function call and display data returned
        System.out.println("Total:"+getTotal(list));
        System.out.println("Average:"+getAverage(list));
        System.out.println("Row 2 value:"+getRowTotal(list,2));
        System.out.println("Column 3 Total :"+getColumnTotal(list,3));
        System.out.println("Highest value in row 1 is :"+getHighest(list,1));
        System.out.println("Lowest value in row 2 is :"+getLowest(list,2));
        
        //Exit program
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    public static int getTotal(int [][]numbers)
    {
        int tot=0;
        for(int row=0;row<numbers.length;row++)
            for(int col=0;col<numbers[row].length;col++)
                tot+=numbers[row][col];
        return tot;
    }
    
    public static double getAverage(int [][]numbers)
    {
        double avg;
        avg= (double)(getTotal(numbers)/(12));
        return avg;
    }
    public static int getRowTotal(int [][]numbers, int index)
    {
        int tot=0;
        for(int col=0;col<4;col++)
            tot+=numbers[index][col];
        return tot;
    }
    public static int getColumnTotal (int [][]numbers, int index)
    {
        int tot=0;
                for(int row=0;row<numbers.length;row++)
                    tot+=numbers[row][index];
        
        return tot;
    }
    
    public static int getHighest(int [][]numbers,int row)
    {
        int high=numbers[row][0];
        for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
            if(numbers[row][i]>high)
                high=numbers[row][i];
        return high;
    
    }
    public static int getLowest(int [][]numbers,int row)
    {
        int low=numbers[row][0];
        for(int i=1;1<4;i++) 
        
            if(numbers[row][i]<low)
                low=numbers[row][i];
        return low;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Side note: don't use magic numbers like `4`. Use the `length` member. Ex: `for(int i = 1; i < numbers[row].length; i++)`

Comment: Because of the infinite loop for this condition _1<4_ in loop. Maybe you want to do _i<4_

Comment: Anyway, you have a typo at `for(int i=1;1<4;i++)`. Should be `i` not `1`

Answer (score 1):

in your `getLowest` function, your for loop only exits when `1 >= 4`, but this will never be true. You should have `i < 4` instead of `1 < 4`

In every iteration of your for loop, it was checking:

- numbers[row][1]<low
- numbers[row][2]<low
- numbers[row][3]<low
- numbers[row][4]<low
- numbers[row][5]<low
- numbers[row][6]<low
- numbers[row][7]<low
- numbers[row][8]<low
- numbers[row][9]<low
- ...

Comment: OHHHH I must have accidentally typed 1 instead of i, what a dumb mistake lol.  Works great now, thanks.

Comment: @user13932723 no problem! Also - some people mentioned better coding practices above that you could try if you wanted to work on your code style.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
for(int i=1;1<4;i++)
```

`1 < 4` is always `true`, so you have infinite loop here until `i == list[row].length` and you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You should use an **IDE** like **IntelliJ IDEA** where such problems are highlited by the editor.

```
class TwoDim {

    public static void main(String... arg) {
        int[][] list = {
                { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
                { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };

        System.out.println("Total: " + getTotal(list));
        System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Average: %.2f\n", getAverage(list));
        System.out.println("Row 2 value: " + getRowTotal(list, 2));
        System.out.println("Column 3 Total: " + getColumnTotal(list, 3));
        System.out.println("Highest value in row 1 is: " + getHighest(list, 1));
        System.out.println("Lowest value in row 2 is: " + getLowest(list, 2));
    }

    public static int getTotal(int[][] list) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < list.length; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < list[row].length; col++)
                sum += list[row][col];

        return sum;
    }

    public static double getAverage(int[][] list) {
        int sum = 0;
        int total = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < list.length; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < list[row].length; col++, total++)
                sum += list[row][col];

        return (double)sum / total;
    }

    public static int getRowTotal(int[][] list, int row) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int col = 0; col < list[row].length; col++)
            sum += list[row][col];

        return sum;
    }

    public static int getColumnTotal(int[][] list, int col) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < list.length; row++)
            sum += list[row][col];

        return sum;
    }

    public static int getHighest(int[][] list, int row) {
        int high = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int col = 0; col < list[row].length; col++)
            high = Math.max(high, list[row][col]);

        return high;
    }

    public static int getLowest(int[][] list, int row) {
        int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int col = 0; col < list[row].length; col++)
            low = Math.min(low, list[row][col]);

        return low;
    }

}
```